# Unicode SendKeys Alternative (Any programming language)

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Before I get to the actual question I will say that altough I'm currently working in Python I will accept a solution in ANY language. I'm mostly a Java programmer but since Java is pretty limited to its JVM I didn't think it would be possible to create this in Java.

**Goal:**

I'm trying to make a program that will intercept keyboard events (I've already done this part using pyHook, this is one of the main reasons I am programming this in Python). Based on these events and the context I need to write unicode characters (ancient-greek) into any focused window (Currently only on Windows OS but an uniform solution that will work on all OS's seems ideal). Basically this is a program that allows me (Classical Language Student) to type Ancient Greek.

**Problems:**

Everything is working great up until the point where I need to send unicode characters, like an alpha, delta or omega, using sendKeys. The hook works perfectly and SendKeys works perfectly with normal ASCII characters. I've tried the following libraries all to no avail: (Code example at the bottom)

- SendKeysCtypes (contrary to what the blog says it does NOT support unicode)
- win32com.client using the shell and SendKeys.
- SendKeys (Another library doing basically the same thing)

Now that I've outlined my current situation I've got the following questions:

**Questions**

*1. Is it at all possible to use unicode characters with SendKeys? (google searches thus far seem to indicate that it is impossible).*
Since this is likely not the case I wonder:
*2. Is there any other library capable of sending unicode characters to the focused window?*

Another thing that has crossed my mind is that I might be using the wrong method altogether (the whole simulating keypress events thing). Any other solution that will help me reach, or at least get closer to, my goal are VERY welcome.

```
#coding: utf-8
import time
import win32com
import win32com.client


shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run('notepad')
time.sleep(0.1)
shell.AppActivate('kladblok')
shell.SendKeys("When Unicode characters are pasted here, errors ensue", 0)
```

Comment: Which encoding are you using? Windows typically uses UTF-16le. Is that what you have used? (More likely you had no encoding at all, or possibly UTF-8.)

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  If the former, you are sending raw 8-bit strings, which are probably being interpreted as ANSI rather than any form of Unicode.

Comment: @Kevin The source file has "coding: utf-8" so that would be my first guess. Raw 8-bit UTF-16le should be fine; how else would you transmit it?

Comment: @triplee: This is on Windows.  All Windows API functions are either ANSI or UTF-16LE.  If you pass an 8-bit Python string, you're probably talking to the former.  But OP's code is UTF-8, which is not ANSI, so the characters are getting munged.

Comment: @Kevin I use python 2.7. I also tried specifically turning the Strings into unicode Strings, but that also failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shell.SendKeys(u"When Unicode characters are pasted here, harmony shall hopefully ensue".encode("utf-16le"), 0)
```

You have not followed up on questions in comments, so this is necessarily speculative.

Comment: Upon closer examination, it seems quite possible that the API is constrained to 8-bit data. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) is, unsurprisingly, uninformative.

Comment: I didn't follow up on questions because I was asleep (timezones can be difficult). However, this example does some interesting stuff. It doesn't print the Unicode characters I send (f.e: α) but instead it mangles the characters. This is an improvement over constant errors :) I think the issue is now in the "encode(utf-16le)" part, I will try some other encodings. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you are actually asking sounds like you are looking for an Input Method Editor. Or is there a specific application you want to use which doesn't allow you to switch to a [Classical Greek keyboard layout](https://www.google.com/search?q=ancient%20greek%20input)?

Comment: I forgot all about keyboard layouts. The modern greek one doesn't have all the functionality you need in Ancient Greek, so I gave up on that path after finding that out. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: So I guss the accept mark on this answer doesn't mean it actually helped? Just curious on behalf of possible future visitors.

Comment: The accept mark means that your previous response at least helped me along my path. I'm now going to change keyboardlayout using a script and the simulate keyPresses with Java. I've already tried it and it works. Sending unicode using SendKeys is impossible it seems. Tough luck.. Thanks for your response!